# php regular expression preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I have following code (php), it will match img-src and replace with new url

```
$rep = array('/', '+', '(', ')');
$with = array('\/', '\+', '\(', '\)');

$match_pattern = '/<img[^<]*src\s*=\s*\"'.str_replace($rep, $with, $source_url).'\"[^>]*>/iUu';
$img_replace_str = '<img src="'.$new_url.'" />';
$post_content = preg_replace($match_pattern, $img_replace_str, $post_content);
```

For images that have src as "http://www.example.com/a.jpg", there is no issue, but for images that have src that contains query string like "http://www.example.com/b.jpg?height=900", it's not matching

I want to match images with and without query string.

Comment: not the answer but you may find array_quote (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) will save you those find and replaces..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's [`preg_quote()`-function](http://php.net/preg_quote) instead of `str_replace()`. It automatically escapes all regular expression special characters (see the docs). That should solve the problem, since your `str_replace()`-solution did not escape `?`, which is a special character in regular expressions:

```
$match_pattern = '/<img[^<]*src\s*=\s*\"'.preg_quote($source_url, '/').'\"[^>]*>/iUu';
```